# Could an all-knowing being create electricity in the year 20 AD?

Tags: technology

I have always found it strange that godly beings who descended from heaven to earth (I'm referring not just to the ones you are familiar with but beings mentioned in various cultures across the world) did not teach humans the basics of technology so that the misery of living in those times could be eased.

For example, at a time like the year 20 AD, couldn't such an all-knowing being have access to metals like copper, create crude wires from it and create a motor? And then show people how to generate hydro-electricity?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82714/discussion-on-question-by-nav-could-an-all-knowing-being-create-electricity-in-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Baghdad Battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baghdad_Battery)

Earliest known appearance was 150 AD, which is a tiny 100 year gap from your target.

In an odd sort of way, religion was actually a big patron of science early on. They relied on marvels they could pass off as divine miracles in order to bolster devotion to their faith. This is one such theory to the origin of the battery however its true purpose has yet been found. Regardless they had a battery which I feel trumps Franklin's kite.

Comment: A much less starry-eyed explanation is that the Baghdad "battery" consists of an iron scroll winding stick, a copper scroll cover, and a jar for storing the scroll in. ("Scroll" is a parchment or papyrus scroll, the form the books had in those times. Today books come in the form of "codices" with bound pages, but in the antiquity they very much preferred scrolls.)

Comment: This answer could be improved with a 1 or 2 sentence description of the device, rather than just a link.